# How to remove all the boot data created by Ubuntu or Fedora?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, fedora, uefi

I'm trying to reinstall Linux in one of my two hard drives.

The problem is something went wrong previously and it seems to have been persisted into a boot sector or something. So now when I try to install Ubuntu the graphics are messed up, and when I try with Fedora I see a black screen.

In the BIOS, when I want to select the order for boot, I see many old options and that might be the problem, eg:

DVD, ubuntu, fedora, DISK2 (Windows), more options... (these things are EFI or UEFI, not sure what that is or how to clean this up)

I tried deleting the partitions in the disk where Ubuntu and Fedora were installed, but this didn't fix anything, I'm still not able to reinstall.

I just want to keep Windows in one drive, and a fresh install of Linux in the other drive. All I want is to be able to run the DVD install, but the graphics are messed up.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The persistent boot information you're seeing is being stored in NVRAM. You can modify it from Linux *booted in EFI mode* by using the `efibootmgr` utility. For instance:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
Timeout: 10 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0008,0006,0007
Boot0000* rEFInd boot manager   HD(2,1b8,64000,f1b7598e-baa8-16ea-4ef6-3ff3b606ac1e)File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0006* Hard Drive    BIOS(2,0,00)SATA: ST32000542AS            .
Boot0007* CD/DVD Drive  BIOS(3,0,00)PATA: HP DVD Writer 1040r     .
Boot0008* INTERNAL EFI SHELL: ST32000542AS  ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)ATAPI(1,0,0)HD(2,1b8,64000,f1b7598e-baa8-16ea-4ef6-3ff3b606ac1e)File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)
```

This shows the EFI boot manager entries. If you wanted to delete one, you'd use a combination of the `-B` and `-b` options, as in:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -b 8 -B
```

That example deletes `Boot0008` from the listing. Type `man efibootmgr` for more on how to use this tool. There are ways to manage this information from Windows, from an EFI shell, and sometimes even from within the firmware's setup utility, too.

That said, deleting old boot entries is unlikely to fix video problems with a new installation. Unfortunately, such problems have been common for the past few months, particularly when using proprietary video drivers in EFI-mode boots. I therefore recommend you avoid the proprietary drivers. The `nomodeset` kernel option (passed via GRUB or whatever boot loader you're using) sometimes helps. Other times there are very hardware-specific workarounds. On rare occasion, you may find that returning the computer in favor of another model is the simplest fix.

Answer (score -1):

As Windows is on a seperate disk, the easiest way (under Linux) would be to zero the first sector of the drive.     You can do this from a command line (as root) by typing dd if=/dev/zero bs=512 count=1 of=/dev/TargetDisk   (where Target disk is something like sda or sdb).   This will remove the partition information and the boot loader from the disk - so you want to make doubly sure you are not acting on your windows drive.

Comment: EFI-based computers don't store boot loaders in the first sector of the disk. Furthermore, such computers typically use GPT, which stores copies of the partition table in 33 sectors *after* the first sector *and* in 33 sectors at the end of the disk. Therefore, this advice will do no good.